# Older server version of mongodb than the shell.Unable to connect

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I'm trying to connect to mongodb atlas and for that, i'm running this command from the cmd on windows

```
    mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0-****.mongodb.net/test" --username username
```

but on running this command i'm getting this error

```
   MongoDB server version: 3.4.13
   WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
```

My shell version is v3.6.3.How do i connect to the server now?

Comment: That is not an error. It's a warning saying that your shell version is different than the server version, so some features might not work as expected. To fix this, please install the matching MongoDB version on your PC (3.4.13 from the message above).

Comment: @KevinAdistambha I'm getting this error and i'm not able to connect           MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://ds163918.mlab.com:63918/chats
MongoDB server version: 3.4.13
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
2018-03-10T11:48:05.388+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1608:20
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2
exception: login failed

Comment: I'm a bit confused. In the question, the URI string resembles MongoDB Atlas, but your comment seem to suggest that you're trying to connect to mLab. Could you please update the question with the correct URI that you're having issues with? Please also post the full error message as per your comment.

Comment: Having said that, the issue in your comment seems to point that you supplied the wrong username/password (`Authentication failed`, and `login failed`).

Comment: Login failed is an authentication error. Does your login credentials work when connecting through other means like a nodejs app ?